# Python: Assign Labels to Values from a List

Tags: python, label

I have an AscII text file with two columns first column is integer numbers and second column is word labels, I want to define values with the labels so `MLKR = 348`, `CLRD = 449.3`, etc.

Here is how I load the AscII file

```
with open('tops.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n').split('\t') for line in open('tops.txt')]
```

Which gives me this output

```
[['348', 'MLKR'], ['449.3', 'CLRD'], ['667', 'SSPK'], ['891.2', 'MNVL'], ['992.2', 'DEIT'], ['1011', 'PEKISKO']]
```

Now what I need to know is how to use the list to assign labels with vales so

```
MLKR = 348
CLRD = 449.3
SSPK = 667
MNVL = 891.2
DEIT = 992.2
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and most direct way is with a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

```
d = { label: value for value,label in lines }

print d['MLKR']
```

If you want the value as a number rather than a string, it's a simple change:

```
d = { label: float(value) for value,label in lines }
```

Comment: The explicit readability in what's going where and how it's happening is useful.

Comment: is there a way to get the values out of '348' so it just reads as 348?

Comment: @AndyRoo I've added that to the answer, if that's not what you're looking for please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using `dict`.  After getting the output in `lines`, you can use:

```
temp ={}
for x in lines:
    temp[x[1]] = x[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {}    
for x in lines:
        dict[x[1]] = x[0]
```

Where x[1]  will be label.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary to hold the key/value pairs, so that every time you call MLKR you'll get your 348, and so on.

```
myDict = { k[0]:k[1] for k in lst }
```